# Check if a method is invoked inside another method in all execution paths by Roslyn

Tags: c#, roslyn, roslyn-code-analysis

Using Roslyn, how can I check the body of a method to determine whether another method is always invoked before returning? For example, in an OWIN middleware, I want to check if the next method is called in all execution paths.

```cs
try
{
    await next();
}
catch
{
   Console.WriteLine("Error"); // the next() is not invoked
}
```

or

```cs
if(condition)
   return; // The next method invocation is ignored

await next();
```

Comment: Have you considered that this may require solving [the halting problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halting_problem)?

Comment: Yes. It is. But I think ignoring loops, can simplify the problem to a tree traversal.